# Resize button with autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I have button at the bottom of the view, that have to be 120 points height on iPhone 5 and 105 on iPhone 4. Can this be accomplished with auto layout? Or I've to check size of screen in code and then change button height?

Answer (score 1):

1. Under Autolayout, views don't have frames at viewDidLoad. Try your code in viewWillAppear: or viewDidLayoutSubviews.
2. Under Autolayout, you don't set frames. You edit constraints instead. Setting a frame will work until the next layout pass, when your layout will revert to that described by your constraints.
3. To size a button to fit a subview, you can try something like this (in visual format language): |-[theView]-| but it would depend what constraints are in place from your xib.